# Jupytertheme Applying Issues(a partial apply problem)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, themes

You have installed jupitertheme.
and the jupitertheme commands, such as the jt-l command, are executed.

However, even if do refresh after using a theme application command jt-t onedork,
the theme does not apply.

Strangely, the error output of the markdown cell looks like the theme has been applied.

Jupytertheme doesn't seem to be working properly. How do I fix it?

[before apply theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqGY2.png)

[after apply theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iuHN.png)

install jupytertheme, try to apply jupytertheme

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.